# Confidence intervals vs law of the iterated logarithm

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, estimation

Let $X_i$ be iid random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$. Let $S_n=\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ denote the sample mean. By CLT it is well known that $(S_n - \frac{1.96}{\sqrt n}, S_n + \frac{1.96}{\sqrt n})$ is an asymptotic $95\%$ confidence interval for $\mu$.

By the law of the iterated logarithm, $\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt {\log \log n} }(S_n-\mu)$ has $\limsup$ equal to $\sqrt 2$ almost surely. Thus for almost all $w$, we have $\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt {\log \log n} }(S_n-\mu) \approx \sqrt 2$ infinitely often, thus $ S_n \approx \mu +\frac{\sqrt {2 \log \log n}}{\sqrt n }$ infinitely often.

For large $n$, $\sqrt {2 \log \log n}$ is much bigger than $1.96$, which seems to contradict the confidence interval. Can someone shed light on this  paradox (if there is any) ?

Comment: have you read wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm

Comment: @seanv507 how does it help ?

Comment: Paying attention to the figure included in this article might help.